# firemonkey location sensor status dont change

Tags: android, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

my app is showing the location long and lat and it is working well

but when i have to detect the location sensor status
like on , of , working , error,...
it have some problem

my idea was this code :

```
  Case LocationSensor1.Sensor.State of
        TSensorState.Added : label5.Text:='2';
        TSensorState.Removed : label5.Text:='3';
        TSensorState.Initializing : label5.Text:='4';
        TSensorState.Ready : label5.Text:='ready';
        TSensorState.NoData : label5.Text:='6';
        TSensorState.AccessDenied : label5.Text:='7';
        TSensorState.Error : label5.Text:='8';
        else label5.Text:='error';
  End;
```

but when i turn on or off the gps it is `ready` every time

how can i detect and show the gps sensor status ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a class extending the `LocationListener` class. You will be notified of the GPS status changes by two callback functions : `onProviderEnabled`, which will be called when the GPS is enabled, and `onProviderDisabled` when it is disabled.

To register your listener, use  `((LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)).requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, myLocationListener);`
.

Comment: where this class must register? i have to know the current status of location sensor,maybe user activated the gps before run my app ?!!

Comment: Your app needs to listen, so that's where the listener must be registered...If the GPS is already on, location changes will be provided to you in the `OnLocationChanged`callback function.

Comment: Or you should use the `GpsStatus.Listener` class.